How to use commands to enable desktop sharing and control in Ubuntu 24.04? Genome wayland
How can I use script(commands) to automatically set up screen sharing and control in the default environment of Ubuntu 24.04?
Although I know that desktop sharing can be enabled manually as follows https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/remote-login.html.en, I don't know if it can be simplified using scripts to enable.
This is simple under x11, but now that Ubuntu has switched to Wayland, it confuses me.
